# What is Unanswered questions tab

Tags: discussion

today I was surfing the site while I caught upto a tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

But the questions there are already answered.

[image]

What do actually mean by Unanswered Question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the answers have upvotes, or have been accepted by the OP.

[image]

Comment: So answers have to be voted up in case to be counted as an answer for a post. Why is it so?!

Comment: Because upvotes (in theory) demonstrate that an answer is useful.

Comment: Oh, so only **usefull** answers are counted?! :)

Comment: That's right.  Unanswered questions are questions that have no "useful" answers yet.

Comment: No, @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan, answers do not need to upvoted; questions with an accepted (possible zero or negatively scored) answer are considered answered as well.

Comment: So if I add your answer to his, it would be like any answer that helps a user is considered as an answer otherwise it is just a post! This would be the joint answer then?! @Arjan

Comment: Pretty much.  Note that I did edit my answer to incorporate his insight.